# UIView frame reset automatically while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

A `UIScrollView` contains 5 `UIView`s. Basically I want to expand and collapse them, when user touches any one of `UIView`.

**Code for animating `globalPressReleasesView` to expand:**

```
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"Expand" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

                                [globalPressReleasesView setFrame:CGRectMake(globalPressReleasesView.frame.origin.x, globalPressReleasesView.frame.origin.y, globalPressReleasesView.frame.size.width, globalPressReleasesView.frame.size.height + [globalPressReleasesArray count]*105)];

                                [financialPressReleasesView setFrame:CGRectMake(financialPressReleasesView.frame.origin.x, financialPressReleasesView.frame.origin.y + [globalPressReleasesArray count]*105, financialPressReleasesView.frame.size.width, financialPressReleasesView.frame.size.height)];


                                [newOnCscView setFrame:CGRectMake(newOnCscView.frame.origin.x, newOnCscView.frame.origin.y + [globalPressReleasesArray count]*105, newOnCscView.frame.size.width, newOnCscView.frame.size.height)];

                                [latestEventsView setFrame:CGRectMake(latestEventsView.frame.origin.x, latestEventsView.frame.origin.y + [globalPressReleasesArray count]*105, latestEventsView.frame.size.width, latestEventsView.frame.size.height)];

                                [latestCaseStudiesView setFrame:CGRectMake(latestCaseStudiesView.frame.origin.x, latestCaseStudiesView.frame.origin.y + [globalPressReleasesArray count]*105, latestCaseStudiesView.frame.size.width, latestCaseStudiesView.frame.size.height)];

                                [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height + [globalPressReleasesArray count]*105)];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

**Other xib properties:**

each `UIView` clipped
`scrollview.autoresize = YES`

**Issue:**

'globalPressReleasesView' expands perfectly, but when I scroll my `scrollview`. `globalPressReleasesView` frame reset itself to original frame values defined in xib.

Can somebody guess what the issue is?

Comment: once check scrollview delegate methods

Comment: yes tried, this is how I got to know, values of all contained `UIView`s frames is getting reset. `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Comment: check globalPressReleasesView frame in this method?

Comment: I have come to this conclusion after trying the same. globalPressReleasesView frame values get replaced automatically to previous values. On first pause to breakpoint, it prints expanded frame value, but on the second stop it returns old frame values. This is how every View returns back to its old position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's simplify the code a little:

```
CGFloat heightDifference = [globalPressReleasesArray count] * 105.0f;

CGRect globalPressReleasesViewFrame = globalPressReleasesView.frame;
globalPressReleasesViewFrame.size.height += heightDifference;
globalPressReleasesView.frame = globalPressReleasesViewFrame;

NSArray* movedViews = @[financialPressReleasesView, newOnCscView, latestEventsView, latestCaseStudiesView];

for (UIView* movedView in movedViews) {
   CGRect movedViewFrame = movedView.frame;
   movedViewFrame.origin.y += heightDifference;
   movedView.frame = movedViewFrame
}

CGSize contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;
contentSize.height += heightDifference;
[scrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
```

Now it's very clear what the code does.

The code appears to be absolutely correct. I would recommend you to check to what values are you setting the frames (either `NSLog` or breakpoint).

Note there are only two ways a view frame can be changed.
1. You change it in code
2. It's autoresized because you have changed it's ancestor's frame (or when the user's switches portrait/landscape mode).

Comment: I have put breakpoint on scrollview delegate to identify when UIView get changed. When I start scrolling UIScrollView, the first value for UIView frame is good, then onwards it changes itself to previous values. Can I put breakpoint somewhere else to get this done.

Comment: I had changed the way I was coding it. I have taken those `UIView`s as the sections of `UITableView` and tableview properties itself controls everything.. :)